# Create Background Color and Line for Tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Goal:
Make passive tab to have another background color.
The selected tab has already a white background color based on preselection.
Between passive tab there should be a line between them, same color between active and passive tab.

Problem:
How do you create a background color to the passive tab and a line between passive tab?

INfo:
*I'm using Bootstrap 3
*I have only use paint in order to display the picture below in order to facilitate the communication.
[image]

Comment: What'sUP sir, how can get your  reputation 4252, anyway you don't know how to ask good question

Comment: I'm not interrested in point!

Comment: yeah  me too  sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood you correctly. You need these changes in your CSS.

```css
.nav-tabs>li>a {
  background: #efefef ;
  margin-right: 0 !important;  
}

.nav-tabs>li>a:not(.active) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a {
  background: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!